# Optimize NumPy iterating through image and changing values

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to optimize this snippet of code? With my current `im` value, it is taking me ~28 seconds. Wondering if I could reduce this time.

```
im = output_image[-min_xy[1]:-min_xy[1] + image_2.shape[0], -min_xy[0]:-min_xy[0] + image_2.shape[1]]
    for idx, rk in enumerate(im):
        for ix, k in enumerate(rk):
            image_2[idx][ix] = avg(im[idx][ix], image_2[idx][ix])
```

`type(image_2)` and `type(im)` is `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

`im.shape` and `image_2.shape` is `(2386, 3200, 3)`

what my `avg()` does is

```
def avg(a1, a2):
    if [0., 0., 0.] in a1:
        return a2
    else:
        return (a1 + a2) / 2
```

NOTE: `a1` is an array of size 3 ex: `array([ 0.68627451,  0.5372549 ,  0.4745098])`

Comment: Try to see if your algorithm behaves like any matrix transformations or operations?

Comment: With `if [0., 0., 0.] in a1` its checking if **anyone in `a1` is zero**. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: @Liondancer That doesn't answer my question, which was - With `if [0., 0., 0.] in a1:`, are you trying to check if `ALL` elements in `a1` are zeros OR if `ANY` one element in `a1` is zero?

Comment: @Divakar if ALL elements in a1 are zeros sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only obstacle to vectorization seemed to be that `IF` conditional in `avg`. To get past it, simply use the choosing capability of `np.where` and thus have our solution like so -

```
avgs = (im + image_2)/2.0
image_2_out = np.where((im == 0).any(-1,keepdims=1), image_2, avgs)
```

Note that this assumes with `if [0., 0., 0.] in a1`, you meant to check for `ANY` one match. If you meant to check for `ALL` zeros, simply use `.all` instead of `.any`.

Alternatively, to do in-situ edits in `image_2`, use a mask for `boolean-indexing` -

```
mask = ~(im == 0).any(-1)
image_2[mask] = avgs[mask]
```